# how to float video playing inside an iframe src on scroll ( when video goes out of viewport )

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, iframe

My use case is simple as shown in this [codepen for direct video tags](https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/full/VMaRvX)

```
<section class="videowrapper videoTag">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close-button"></a>
        <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
        <i class="fa fa-arrows-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <video class="initial_video" loop="" controls="">
            <source id="" src="https://d2cstorage-a.akamaihd.net/atl/Brunomars/Bruno-VersaceOnTheFloor.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </section>
```

The only difference is that I have a mix of direct video and iframe tags.

```
 <div class="video-wrapper"> 
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="close-button"></a>
  <iframe   src="https://codepen.io/technotech/full/poRqdvN"></iframe>
</div>
```

i.e.
I have multiple iframes which have src URL as HTML/page (video are in this HTML/page). Once the page(containing multiple iframes and direct video tags) gets loaded, the user clicks on any one video(either direct video tag's video or iframe's video) to play and if it goes out of viewport then it should float.

if another video gets played while 1st one is floating, then 2nd video should replace 1st one on the float position if 2nd video goes out of the viewport

here is the [codepen2](https://codepen.io/technotech/pen/mdRaqJY) which I created for my use case. I tried the way used in the above [codepen for direct video tags](https://codepen.io/aravi-pen/full/VMaRvX) but it's not working for iframe HTML src videos as it's not able to inject events and id to those videos I guess.

please excuse me if I missed something.

Comment: Instead of trying float the video player inside iframe, have you tried float iframe instead?

Comment: actually, anything will work for me either video or complete iframe as iframe source has only video element on the page and yes, i have tried, it's just that I need to capture the play event when someone plays video inside an iframe and then  work on the floating part, based on visibility on the viewport, but before that, I need to add an event to that video element to capture it, but on first-time page load, I can't get the inside element of iframe